# AsyncTask+CheckBox

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, интересует вопрос: нужно в функцию AsyncTask послать несколько строк, в зависимости от того, какие чекбоксы отмечены. Ну, например, если отмечены из чекбоксов 1,3,5, то послать строки так

```
AsyncTask().execute(r1,r3,r5);
```

Пробовал через

```
String s[];
if (cb1.isChecked()) {
    s[nmbr] = r1;
    nmbr++;
    //new DownloadVkTask().execute(res);
}
if (cb2.isChecked()) {
    s[nmbr] = r2;
    nmbr++;
}
if (cb3.isChecked()) {
    s[nmbr] = r3;
    nmbr++;
}
if (cb4.isChecked()) {
    s[nmbr] = r4;
    nmbr++;
}
if (cb5.isChecked()) {
    s[nmbr] = r5;
    nmbr++;
}
if (cb6.isChecked()) {
    s[nmbr] = r6;
    nmbr++;
}
if (cb7.isChecked()) {
    s[nmbr] = r7;
    nmbr++;
}
AsyncTask().execute(s);
```

- не работает, что делать?

Comment: можно поточнее про 1 вариант?
Вы сказали что нужно передавать параметры переменной длины.
Каким образом это сделать для моей ситуации?  Что бы сформировать запрос в зависимости от выбранных чекбоксов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

внутри асинктасков (и потоков в целом) можно получать доступ к элементам UI только через конструкции onProgressChange, хэндлеры или post
Например так

```
cb1.post(new Runnable(){
    public void Run(){
        if (cb5.isChecked()) {
            s[nmbr] = r5;
            nmbr++;
        }
    }
});
```

При этом все члены использующиеся внутри Run (например сам cb5) должны быть объявлены статическими либо final

Answer (score 0):

Может потому, что на вход execute нужно передавать не массив, а параметры переменной длины? Как написано у вас выше: r1, r2, r3. Так и нужно передавать. По идее. Либо поменяйте входящий параметр в классе на массив строк.